# "Would-be" meaning "potential": must it be hyphenated?

Tags: idioms, hyphenation

Suppose I write, "Giving exams in class thwarts would-be cheaters."  Must "would-be" have a hyphen?  Or would it be preferable to write it without a hyphen?  (It seems easier to read with the hyphen.)

Comment: No. Different people and different editors will give you their opinions, but there's no definitive source for punctuation or spacing of compound phrases. If you use it a lot, figure out what suits you, and then stick to it. It's **your** language, if you're speaking it. Or if you're writing it.

Comment: Sounds like an answer.  If you make it one, I can upvote it. (However, I make a distinction between what's appropriate for what we call "formal writing" and what we, the folk do, which has broadly varying norms and is the ultimate source of what counts as a language. For information about the later, I would rather consult linguists than my own intuitions, were I in doubt.  Either way, it's not my language; it's ours.  Otherwise I might just say that dasalk fetra umerskya--if I thought I could remember what those just-invented words meant later. :-)

Comment: You can even write it as one word and really give your editors a run for their money: *wouldbe cheaters*.

Comment: Ugh. That's not for me.  Have at it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many grammar guides, such as [grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) and [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-a-hyphen?page=all), do advise writers to use a hyphen when compound adjectives come before the noun they modify, but as John Lawler commented, it's not a definitive rule. It's pretty much like the Oxford comma; there are people who'll complain if you use it and there are people who'll complain if you don't.

The only time a  hyphen is definitely necessary is if leaving it out would cause ambiguity. For example, *a man eating alligator* could refer to either a man who is eating alligator meat or an alligator who eats people, but *a man-eating alligator* is unambiguously the latter.